# Converting long to int unsure why about result

Tags: c#, long-integer

So I am converting a long into an int. The long number is 1302165637746283555 and it converts into 1537778179 as an int.  I have been unable to find documentation on why it does this.  How does it come up with the second numbers and is there a way to convert the int number back to the long number?
Here is my code.

```
DateTime creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(@"c:\windows\setupact.log");
FILETIME fl1 = new FILETIME();
            fl1.dwLowDateTime = unchecked((int)creationTime.ToFileTime());
```

Comment: You must be deceiving us because `(int)1302165637746283555L != 1537778179`.

Comment: Through some very lucky googling I found it (int)(hFT1 & 0xFFFFFFFF);  where hFT1 is a long

Answer (score 9):

Converting a `long` into an `int` *may* (and in this case **will**) cause a loss of data. There is no way to get that lost data back. So no, there is no way to convert from long to int and back again in your situation.

You are asking the equivalent of, "I poured a five gallon bucket of water into a three gallon bucket. Is there any way to get five gallons of water back again?"

Comment: Nicely put. And plenty of documentation (and stackoverflow questions) to be found about it too.

Comment: Nicely put - although it is six gallon bucket into three gallon bucket :)